# Can somebody check whether I have calculated this contour integral correctly?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration

$$\int_{|z-\frac{1}{2}|=1}\frac{e^{-iz}}{z(z-1)(z^2-1)} dz$$

I used the Residue Theorem and got this answer:

$2i\pi-\pi e^i -\frac{3}{2}\pi i e^i$

Is there also some software that can compute these so that I can do some practice as well?

Comment: The answer would be right if you used $e^{+i z}$ in the numerator.  Alas...

Comment: YOu're right I missed that. Thanks!